# Unable to determine class for field type during upgrade

Tags: 8, updating, debugging

I'm getting the following error when I am updating my site's core and contrib modules. I'm at a loss as to how I would go about finding the issue. I've gone to `views.views.inc` line 181 and looked there. This line is what generates the error, however I don't know why there is a field type of `''`.

```
RuntimeException: Unable to determine class for field type '' found in the 'field.storage.' configuration in /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/field/src/FieldStorageConfigStorage.php:164 Stack trace:
#0 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php(193): Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigStorage->mapFromStorageRecords(Array, Array)
#1 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(279): Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->doLoadMultiple(NULL)
#2 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/views.views.inc(181): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple()
#3 [internal function]: views_views_data()
#4 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(392): call_user_func_array('views_views_dat...', Array)
#5 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php(243): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('views', 'views_data')
#6 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php(160): Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData()
#7 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/Derivative/ViewsEntityRow.php(91): Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content')
#8 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator.php(101): Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array)
#9 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator.php(87): Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array)
#10 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(284): Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions()
#11 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(175): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions()
#12 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryCachedTrait.php(22): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions()
#13 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Factory/ContainerFactory.php(16): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('node_rss')
#14 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/PluginManagerBase.php(83): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('node_rss', Array)
#15 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/DisplayPluginBase.php(817): Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('node_rss')
#16 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/style/StylePluginBase.php(122): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('row')
#17 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/DisplayPluginBase.php(820): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->init(Object(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable), Object(Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Feed), Array)
#18 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutable.php(882): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('style')
#19 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutable.php(1842): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->initStyle()
#20 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/PathPluginBase.php(132): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->getTitle()
#21 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/PathPluginBase.php(220): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\PathPluginBase->getRoute('frontpage', 'feed_1')
#22 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/modules/views/src/EventSubscriber/RouteSubscriber.php(120): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\PathPluginBase->collectRoutes(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection))
#23 [internal function]: Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\RouteSubscriber->routes()
#24 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(146): call_user_func(Array)
#25 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(83): Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
#26 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/includes/common.inc(1160): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
#27 /var/aegir/platforms/d-8.6.7-2019020101-php7.2-redis/web/core/includes/utility.inc(52): drupal_flush_all_caches()
#28 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/cache.drush.inc(302): drupal_rebuild(Object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#29 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_cache_rebuild()
#30 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#31 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#32 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#33 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#34 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(462): drush_main()
#35 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(369): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#36 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#37 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
#38 {main}
```

Comment: Did you run update.php, `yourwebsite.com/update.php` and cleared all caches?

Comment: I'm using Aegir as a hosting deployment system. When I upgrade it goes through the update.php. I did clear cache and try again to be certain. I still get the issue.